# How to pass information between Controller in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I successfully logged a user in, however, when I save the userID in userLogin(Profile dto) which is in ProfileDataAccessObject.java. I can't seem to access the userID in other Controller or DataAccessObject class.

LoginController.java

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable {

@FXML private TextField username; // where the user enters their username

@FXML private PasswordField password; // where the user enters the password

@FXML private Button loginBtn; // authenticates users details when clicked

@FXML public Label wrongLogin; // label displayed when login is unsuccessful

@FXML private Hyperlink accountRegistrationLink; // when clicked take user to signup

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

}

public void userLogin(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    if (actionEvent.getSource().equals(loginBtn)) {

        Connection connection = DatabaseHandlerSingleton.getDatabaseHandlerSingleton();

        profile = new Profile(username.getText(), password.getText());

        ProfileDataAccessObject profileDataAccessObject = new ProfileDataAccessObject(connection);

        if (profileDataAccessObject.login(profile) == null) {
            System.out.println("Login failed");

        } else {
            //change scene to workspace
            FactorySceneViewCreator.changeScene(actionEvent, "workspace");
        }
    }
}
```

}

WorkspaceController.java

```
public class WorkspaceController implements Initializable {

   private LoginController loginController = new LoginController();
   
   @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
       System.out.println(loginController.profile.toString());
   }
}
```

Console Output:

```
 Profile{id=0, email='null', username='null', password='null', user=null, session=null, profilePicturePath='null', encryption=null}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are doing to try to access the user id in the second controller. Create and post a [mre] (surely the database access stuff is irrelevant to the question) that we can copy and run to see what you're doing. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml) might answer your question.

Comment: I have other tables in the database that reference userID, so I wanted to store it in the model layer and insert it as a foreign key in the database for tables that reference it. I'll check out the link

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want to do. I just don’t see where you’re attempting to do it, so it’s impossible to see where you’re going wrong. Create and post a [mre] that does nothin higher than try to pass a user id from one controller to another.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx may also be useful

Comment: I've created the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: If you create a new `LoginController` instance, then of course it will have its own `profile` instance which won’t be the same as the one you stored the user id in. Pass the profile object to the workspace controller using the technique in the first link.

Comment: Thanks, the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml worked. Much appreciated